# Copy data from certain array positions and adding them to the start of the array

Tags: php

I have the following array, I want to take the data from positions 1 & 2 and add them into the array at position 0, but only if the id is unique. I'd also like to set the quantities of the copied items to 0.

```php
$arr = [
    [
        [
            'id' => 39235995,
            'quantity' => 1,
            'price' => 2.81
        ],
        [
            'id' => 39235995,
            'quantity' => 1,
            'price' => 2.81
        ]
    ],
    [
        [
            'id' => 39235995,
            'quantity' => 1,
            'price' => 2.81
        ],
        [
            'id' => 39236029,
            'quantity' => 1,
            'price' => 2.952
        ]
    ],
    [
        [
            'id' => 39236015,
            'quantity' => 1,
            'price' => 3.333
        ]
    ]
];
```

This was my attempt. It's copied the items and set their quantities to zero but hasn't taken into account the unique id's and has also added them to the end of the array.

```
// Separate out the quantities for each product, one per array
$resultArr = [];
foreach($total_products as $item){
  for($i = 0; $i < $item['quantity']; $i++){
      $resultArr[] = array(
        'id' => $item['id'],
        'quantity' => 1,
        'price' => $item['price'],
      );
  }
}

// Divide up into the correct amount of parcels
$parcel_size = 2;
$parcels = array_chunk($resultArr, $parcel_size);


// Add all products into the first array so it's reduces quantities down in the original order
$new_orders = array_slice($parcels, 1);
foreach($new_orders as $order){
  $parcels[] = array(
    'id' => $order['id'],
    'quantity' => 0,
    'price' => $order['price'],
  );
}
```

This is what I'd like to create, where am I going wrong?

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 39235995
                    [quantity] => 1
                    [price] => 2.81
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 39235995
                    [quantity] => 1
                    [price] => 2.81
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 39236029
                    [quantity] => 0
                    [price] => 2.952
                ) 

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 39236015
                    [quantity] => 0
                    [price] => 3.333
                )                               

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 39235995
                    [quantity] => 1
                    [price] => 2.81
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 39236029
                    [quantity] => 1
                    [price] => 2.952
                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 39236015
                    [quantity] => 1
                    [price] => 3.333
                )

        )

)
```

---

The array created based on @Terminator-Barbapapa's answer:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 39235995
                    [quantity] => 1
                    [price] => 2.81
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 39235995
                    [quantity] => 1
                    [price] => 2.81
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 39236015
                    [quantity] => 0
                    [price] => 3.333
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 39235995
                    [quantity] => 1
                    [price] => 2.81
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 39236029
                    [quantity] => 1
                    [price] => 2.952
                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 39236015
                    [quantity] => 1
                    [price] => 3.333
                )

        )

)
```

Comment: It might be easier to read the arrays if they are written as PHP code, rather than `print_r()` output.

Comment: @noam I've just updated the question and added the original array, does that help?

Comment: What is your intention when you use `array_chunk()`? You should note that it returns the first 2 (=`$parcel_size`) elements of `$resultArr`. I am not sure this is your desired results.

Comment: @noam `array_chunk()` is separating each array out to be a maximum of two items per array. Essentially we can only fit two items into our parcels. That part works as far as I can see

Comment: What do you mean by _“but only if the id is unique”_?

Comment: You should just be aware that it chunks the upper most level of the array. I suspect you want to chunk the second level. You can use a temporary print to see the content of `$parcels` right after it is created to make sure.

Comment: @CBroe So each id is a product, the first product in the second array is already in the first array, so I don't want to copy that one into the first array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run through your first order collecting the ids of the parcels in it and then copy the parcels with an id that don't match any of the collected ids with the following code:

```
$ids = array();
foreach ( $new_orders as $key => $order ) {

    //Collect ids from first order  
    if ( $key == 0 ) {
        foreach ( $order as $parcel ) {
            array_push( $ids, $parcel['id'] );
        }

    //Copy parcels to first order
    } else {
        foreach ( $order as $parcel ) {
            if ( !in_array( $parcel['id'], $ids ) ) {
                $parcel['quantity'] = 0;
                array_push( $new_orders[0], $parcel );
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Before copying the parcel the quantity will be set to zero.

Array used as input:

```
$new_orders = array(
    array(
        array(
            'id' => 39235995,
            'quantity' => 1,
            'price' => 2.81,
        ),
        array(
            'id' => 39235995,
            'quantity' => 1,
            'price' => 2.81,
        ),
    ),

    array(
        array(
        'id' => 39235995,
        'quantity' => 1,
        'price' => 2.81,
        ),
        array(
        'id' => 39236029,
        'quantity' => 1,
        'price' => 2.952,
        )
    ),

    array(
        array(
        'id' => 39236015,
        'quantity' => 1,
        'price' => 3.333,
        ),
    ),
);
```

Comment: I've used your array as input and in my test it gave the desired output. I've updated my answer to include the array I used as input. Maybe you can see if I made a mistake there?

Comment: Thank you so much, that's sorted it.